# Precalculus Composition of Functions Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, word-problem

The prompt: Amparo bought a jacket with a \$50 gift certificate she received as a birthday present. The jacket was marked 33% off, and the sales tax in her area is 5.5%. If she paid $45.95 for the jacket, use composition of functions to determine the original price of the jacket. (45.95 was the price after they redeemed the gift certificate)

a.) Write a function $g(x)$ for the price after the gift certificate was used and then determine the price before the gift certificate was used.

b.) Write s function $t(x)$ for the price after the discount was applied and then determine the original price/

c.) Write a function $d(x)$ for the price after the discount was applied and then determine the original price.

d.) Write a simplified composition of functions $p(x)=g(t(d(x)))$ to find the price of any vase where the discount, sales tax, and gift certificate are all accounted for.

e.) If Amparo wanted to get a vase at no additional cost after all discounts, taxes, and their gift certificate was redeemed, what would be the original price of the most expensive vase they could buy?

I am not sure where to start exactly with this question since it needs to be written as a function. I am not sure if this is right, but would you just add 50 to problem a?

a.) $g(x)=45.95x-50$

I am pretty sure that is incorrect, but I am extremely confused. If anyone could help me solve the problems that would be amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is very poorly worded.  b) should this be taxes and not dicounts.  d) where does this vase come about.  e) if she paid 45.95 after applying the gift certificate, how does she get a vase at no additional cost?

Comment: That's what I am confused about too! I have no clue how to approach this problem

Answer (score 1):

$g(x) = x-50\\
g^{-1}(x) = 50 + x$

The gift certificate takes $\$50$ of the final price.  $g^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function that tells us the price before the certificate is applied

$t(x)$ is probably taxes, and not the discount applied twice

$t(x) = 1.055 x$

$d(x) = (1-0.33)x = 0.67 x$

$p(x) = (g\circ t\circ d) (x) = (1.055)(0.67) x - 50\\
p^{-1}(x) = (d^{-1}\circ t^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x) = \frac {x+50}{(1.055)(0.67)}$

Comment: Would you just plug the $45.95 in for x? Since problem A asks for the price before the gift certificate was used would the answer be $95.95?

Comment: In the $p^{-1)$ calculation.  $p$ is what she ultimately paid.  So $p^{-1}$ will give what it was originally marked.

Comment: For t(x) wouldn't it be 1-0.055x to find the price after the sales tax was included?

Comment: If it was $\$100$ before tax, it would be $\$105.50$  after tax.  Now if you knew the after tax price and wanted to back into the before tax price... $\frac{ 105.50}{1.055} = 100$ while $105.50(1-0.055) = 99.6975 $

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. For what the questions are asking would you constantly plug 45.95 in for x or would you plug in the answer before? Also, is the answer to e.)  $135.74? Because once I do everything backwards with 135.74 by the 33% discount then the 5.5% tax and $50 gift certificate I am left with $35.95 instead of $45.95 sorry I am really confused.